# exact sequence of differential

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I was trying to figure out the proof of the following theorem:

> If $C=B / I$, we have an exact sequence $$ I / I^2
>  \stackrel{\delta}{\rightarrow} \Omega_{B / A}^1 \otimes_B C
>  \stackrel{\alpha}{\rightarrow} \Omega_{C / A}^1 \rightarrow 0 $$ where
> for any $b \in I$, if we let $\bar{b}$ denote the image of $b$ in $I /
>  I^2$, then $\delta(\bar{b}):=d b \otimes 1$.

---

The proof goes as follows:

We have $I / I^2=I \otimes_B C$.  it suffices to show that the sequence $$0 \rightarrow \operatorname{Der}_A(C, N) \rightarrow \operatorname{Der}_A(B, N) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_C\left(I / I^2, N\right)=\operatorname{Hom}_B(I, N)$$
is exact for any $C$-module $N$. The last homomorphism associates to any $A$-derivation $d^{\prime}: B \rightarrow N$ its restriction to $I$. **The latter is indeed a homomorphism of $B$-modules because $I N=0$.** It can immediately be seen that sequence is exact.

---

I can't see why $IN$ is zero since $I$ is an arbitrary given ideal and $N$ is a $B$ module there is no reason that $I \subset \text{Ann}(N)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$N$ is not just any $B$-module, it’s a $B$-module where the $B$-action factorizes through $C$ – which means exactly that $I$ annihilates $N$.

Comment: thank you I have checked Hartshorne and Qing Liu's book they don't mention that $N$ has $B$ action factor through $C$? I know to let $N$ has $C$ module structure it needs to have $I \subset \text{Ann}(N)
$, but the book didn't mention that, is it because they have post $\text{Der}(C,N)$ which implicit impose this condition?

Comment: $N$ is explicitly defined as a $C$-module (just after the exact sequence).

Comment: ok , thank you Aphelli